# How can i make any URI authorized as Redirect URI for my Google Cloud APP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, redirect-uri-mismatch

Redirect URI adding section

[image: 1]

Hi there :)

Thanks in advance, actually i was making a wordpress plugin which requries Google OAuth verification and i am making this plugin for all users. But i found that in the Authentiation URL i need to pass a Redirect URI and that needs to be added previously in my Google Cloud app, otherwise that Redirect URI will be considered as Unauthorized.

And Google doesn't allow me to add any wildcard entry as Authorized redirect URI. So, in this case how can any user use my plugin, because i can't know everyones site url and add them into my Cloud App manually.

So, do anyone knows that how can i make any URL authorized as Redirect URI or dynamically add Authorized URI into my Google Cloud app.

I tried adding wildcard URL entries, and also tried removing all URL entries from that list thinking that removing all might be considered as all urls are allowed, but nothing worked for me :(

Comment: You must specify the authorized redirect URI. What you are attempting is a security risk. Your users must create their own Google Clients and client secrets. Do not allow third parties to use yours. If you did, the third party could abuse the tokens after a user authenticates and your app, meaning you, would be responsible.

Comment: OMG, that's an issue... but is there any way to achieve this?